# Software to back up application settings in Windows (including XP)

Tags: windows-xp, backup, migration

I would like to know if there is any (especially free) solution to back up and restore settings from applications (even if only from a whitelist of the most popular ones), both for XP and further versions of Windows.

Most of the applications I see are designed to work in XP solely for the purpose of upgrading to Windows 7 - I would like one that could also transfer settings ***to*** Windows XP.

I know XP is an old system, and that new installs of it are not recommended. This recommendation makes a lot of sense depending on the country, and it does not apply to this case; I'm simply asking for an XP-friendly solution.

Do note that I'm not asking for a way to transfer applications or documents, just settings is more than enough. Anything else is a bonus.

Comment: The problem is with the definition of “settings”. There are countless “settings” in Windows both system-wide and user-specific. And that’s just with Windows itself, let alone settings related to third-party programs. Unfortunately you really will need to be more specific as to your needs.

Comment: @Synetech Any kind of support would be appreciated, for example, just being able to back up settings of popular applications (browsers, IM clients, VoIP, etc) along with simple OS settings such as wallpapers and user account settings (maybe whole user accounts?) would help already. You see, when people call me because "the browser's home page is not the same and I can't figure out how I changed it before" after a reformat, then any help is help I appreciated, even a software that backs up really rudimentary settings is welcome as a suggestion.

Comment: Sadly, settings are scattered throughout the system in numerous formats and places. Some are stored in the registry, some in files, some in this folder, others in a different one. Some in binary files, while yet others in plain-text ones. Unfortunately there is no single repository of setting-locations or backup program that can do-it-all. You best bet is to search for a backup program that supports third-party apps and/or look for application-specific information.

Comment: @Synetech I understand no solution will do-it-all. I understand that settings for some applications could even be quite hard to extract. But a solution for common applications would already be quite nice. Also, maybe somebody has thought about making it extensible. For example, take a look at CCleaner. It cleans settings for many applications (therefore it knows where these are), and some people have [extended it](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/extend-and-enhance-ccleaner-functionality-with-ccenhancer) to a point where even some obscure programs are covered. Something extensible would be cool.

Comment: Yes, that would certainly be sweet. In fact, a long time ago (10+ years) I had the idea of just writing my own backup program that can be easily extended to support any program. Unfortunately I never had enough time to do much work on it.

Comment: @Synetech That's pretty cool! Besides, there seems to be no open-source alternative in the field, I'm honestly thinking about finding some time to write my own. Bibhas' answer has inspired me :D (The only fear I have is people not using it because I'm pretending to write it in .NET 4, do you think that could stop people from using it?)

Comment: Re: Rolling-own; I made and used a system of batch files to automate backups and restores, both at the file/registry level as well as the drive-image level. Unfortunately my backup habit stopped sometime around November 2003. It certainly didn’t help that I keep running out of space. Re: .NET 4; Well I for one wouldn’t simply because I can’t install .NET 3 or higher on my XP SP1 installation. I could use it in my 7 installation though. Re: open-source; Did you already [check SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=backup) for something that could meet your needs?

Comment: @Synetech Uh, didn't search SourceForge, normally I get taken there from Google, so I thougth googling for it was enough. However searching for something like that is proving hard, because it's so specific (and most *backup* programs only backup drives or folders). [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-easy-transfer/) does not give me many relevant results either. I must admire that you managed to bend batch files to your needs, after I met Linux, batch files look like a joke (and their syntax is quite horrible...). Hey, why didn't you update your XP? SP1 is unsafe to use.

Comment: Thanks for the link to alternativeTo. As for SP1, I honestly don’t remember anymore. I installed SP2 when it first came out and found that there were several things I *hated* about it (several of which are no longer relevant). I did a test update to SP3 a few months ago to try to get a newer video driver to work correctly, but quickly reverted back. I don’t remember what the problem was, but I have been considering test-updating again for weeks now. `:-)`

Comment: @Synetech There's some security bugs in SP1 if I can remember correctly (but from your user page I take it you've disabled certain useless services such as the messenger one that can spam you, and things like that), but mostly some software would refuse to install on it. You know, I'm quite fond of XP, it works well, even on dated hardware. XP is running in a 192 MB RAM, 400 MHz CPU my father has, and it amazingly even runs video (at a choppy frame rate), and plays songs streamed in flash player. I'm considering if I should skip 7 when 8 arrives, however (yes, I did not even install 7 yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it manually, here are the locations most software store their data at -

`%AppData%` -

- `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming` in Vista and Windows 7
- `C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data` in XP

`%LocalAppData%` -

- `C:\Users\AppData\Local` in Windows 7
- `C:\Documents and Settings\Local Settings\Application Data` in XP

`C:\ProgramData` in Windows 7.

`C:\Program Files`, and `C:\Program Files (x86)` (64-bit systems only)

Settings at Registry are stored mostly inside -

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\`

This is just a manual effort, I'll post of any software I come across that does the same job.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this made me think about writing a tool to do this. It could prove trivial, considering the benefits (I'll have to re-format a lot of computers in the near future), and if there's really no free, open-source alternative, it'd be a cool project!

Comment: By the way, by trivial, I mean a tool which would take a snapshot of the system, then the user would change settings in his application, and take a second snapshot, then record the places where the application stored the settings. So basically it would be a semi-automated process of adding "supported applications" to a list, and using that list to migrate settings on real machines (the recognition process could be done in a VM), in case anyone's wondering. I understand blindly copying these folders and registry keys would cause havoc.

Comment: I just wanted to note a couple of things: on Linux, backing up configurations is as simple as backing up the home dir. It's effing sweet, everything backed up without a single problem, and quite some applications even. Another thing is that in the future I'll be making my own (humble) app to take care of this, so your answer mostly covers it.

Answer (score 2):

this new tool, called CloneApp can do all this

http://www.mirinsoft.com/index.php/blog/243-new-project-cloneapp-on-the-run

Rather than backing up the system or even the software, it backs up registry keys and configuration files with a pretty convenient gui.

Its a portable app, and you can backup any settings you wish.

There's a pretty extensive list of software it'll back up, and its possible to write new plugins. With the currently installed plugins, click on select installed, and start cloneapp to clone your current settings, and it'll do its thing.

You'll want to make sure any software you're backing up isn't running and it backs up some of your user files as well.

Download, run, and it'll save everything you picked to a folder. Hit restore to restore. 
[image]

While the screenshot's from windows 10, it works in XP as well.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I ended up expanding the answer, since this is a pretty nice piece of software which I've been struggling to remember the name of for ages. I hope the OP will take a look, and write future answers to least this standard ^^. I'll have to try it on an XP box later

Answer (score 1):

Windows Easy Transfer - transfer your data to a new computer. Direcly in Windows 7. Here is something about it: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/transfer-your-data-with-windows-easy-transfer/

I just found this app http://www.pickmeapp.com .
It claims to be application manager. I have no time to test it right now, but here is review:
http://www.softpedia.com/reviews/windows/PickMeApp-Review-390534.shtml

There is also GameSave Manager, if you play games. I use it few years ago and it was perfect: http://www.gamesave-manager.com/

Comment: The problem with Windows Easy Transfer is that I'm sure it won't work if e.g., you want to take something from Windows 8 and put it on Windows 7. About the two alternatives you mention, they seem interesting; I wonder if you can customize them. I think that's important because if it can't automatically pick up one app, having a way to tell it which files and directories to pick (or, for that matter, which ones not to) would be an useful feature. Thanks for the answer, though!